# gfortran openmp no threading

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp

I have a simple Fortran code, and despite the use of the `omp_set_num_threads()` subroutine, I cannot set number of threads, i.e. the output says that I use only 1 thread. I tried also with the `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4` - no result.

I have no idea what is wrong it that pice of code:

```
  program test

  use omp_lib
  implicit none

  integer :: i, tnr,t 

  call omp_set_num_threads( 4 )
  t = omp_get_num_threads()

  write(*,*)'t:',t

  !$omp parallel
  !$omp do
  do i = 1, 20
     tnr = omp_get_thread_num()
     write( *, * ) 'Thread', tnr, ':',  i
  end do
  !$omp end do
  !$omp end parallel

  end program test
```

The output of that code is:

```
 t:           1
 Thread           0 :           1
 Thread           0 :           2
 Thread           0 :           3
 Thread           0 :           4
 Thread           0 :           5
 Thread           0 :           6
 Thread           0 :           7
 Thread           0 :           8
 Thread           0 :           9
 Thread           0 :          10
 Thread           0 :          11
 Thread           0 :          12
 Thread           0 :          13
 Thread           0 :          14
 Thread           0 :          15
 Thread           0 :          16
 Thread           0 :          17
 Thread           0 :          18
 Thread           0 :          19
 Thread           0 :          20
```

Thanks for any kind of tip!

I use gentoo linux, the gcc-4.5.4 compiler has the `openmp` flag activated. The cpu is mobile core i7 2nd generation.

ldd test:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff85fce000)
    libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/libgfortran.so.3      (0x00007fe310460000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe310169000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007fe30ff5b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe30fd45000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe30fb28000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe30f77d000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe30f574000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe310749000)
```

gfortran -v

```
 Using built-in specs.
 COLLECT_GCC=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.5.4/gfortran
 COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/lto-wrapper
 Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 Configured with: /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-4.5.4/work/gcc-4.5.4/configure   --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.5.4 --includedir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/include --datadir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4 --mandir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/man --infodir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/info --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/include/g++-v4 --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --disable-altivec --disable-fixed-point --without-ppl --without-cloog --disable-lto --enable-nls --without-included-gettext --with-system-zlib --enable-obsolete --disable-werror --enable-secureplt --enable-multilib --enable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --enable-libgomp --with-python-dir=/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/python --enable-checking=release --disable-libgcj --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-targets=all --with-  bugurl=http://bugs.gentoo.org/ --with-pkgversion='Gentoo 4.5.4 p1.0, pie-0.4.7'
 Thread model: posix
 gcc version 4.5.4 (Gentoo 4.5.4 p1.0, pie-0.4.7)
```

output of a testmp.f140t.optimized (the one before the *.statistics):

```
;; Function test (MAIN__)

test ()
{
 struct __st_parameter_dt dt_parm.1;
 logical(kind=4) D.1545;
 struct __st_parameter_dt dt_parm.0;
 integer(kind=4) tnr;
 integer(kind=4) t;
 integer(kind=4) i;
 integer(kind=4) i.8;
 integer(kind=4) i.7;
 integer(kind=4) i.6;
 integer(kind=4) tnr.5;
 integer(kind=4) i.4;
 integer(kind=4) t.3;

<bb 2>:
 omp_set_num_threads (&C.1537);
 t.3_1 = omp_get_max_threads ();
 t = t.3_1;
 dt_parm.0.common.filename = &"testmp.f"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1};
 dt_parm.0.common.line = 11;
 dt_parm.0.common.flags = 128;
 dt_parm.0.common.unit = 6;
 _gfortran_st_write (&dt_parm.0);
 _gfortran_transfer_character (&dt_parm.0, &"t:"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1}, 2);
 _gfortran_transfer_integer (&dt_parm.0, &t, 4);
 _gfortran_st_write_done (&dt_parm.0);
 i = 1;
 i.4_2 = i;
 if (i.4_2 <= 20)
 goto <bb 3>;
else
 goto <bb 5>;

<bb 3>:
tnr.5_3 = omp_get_thread_num ();
tnr = tnr.5_3;
dt_parm.1.common.filename = &"testmp.f"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1};
dt_parm.1.common.line = 16;
dt_parm.1.common.flags = 128;
dt_parm.1.common.unit = 6;
_gfortran_st_write (&dt_parm.1);
_gfortran_transfer_character (&dt_parm.1, &"Thread"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1}, 6);
_gfortran_transfer_integer (&dt_parm.1, &tnr, 4);
_gfortran_transfer_character (&dt_parm.1, &":"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1}, 1);
_gfortran_transfer_integer (&dt_parm.1, &i, 4);
_gfortran_st_write_done (&dt_parm.1);
i.6_4 = i;
D.1545_5 = i.6_4 == 20;
i.7_6 = i;
i.8_7 = i.7_6 + 1;
i = i.8_7;
if (D.1545_5 != 0)
goto <bb 5>;
else
goto <bb 4>;

<bb 4>:
goto <bb 3>;

 <bb 5>:
 return;

 }

;; Function main (main)

main (integer(kind=4) argc, character(kind=1) * * argv)
{
static integer(kind=4) options.2[8] = {68, 255, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1};
integer(kind=4) D.1552;

<bb 2>:
_gfortran_set_args (argc_1(D), argv_2(D));
_gfortran_set_options (8, &options.2[0]);
test ();
D.1552_3 = 0;
return D.1552_3;

}
```

Comment: Did you compile with `gfortran -fopenmp...`?

Comment: Works for me on gfortran-4.8 with the exception that I moved `t = omp_get_num_threads()` to the `parallel` region.

Comment: This code works for me without changing anything on Ubuntu 12.04 with gfortran 4.6.3. I compiled it via `gfortran -fopenmp -o "test_omp" "test_omp.f90"`

Comment: @keyle - so "tnr" shows values 0,1,2 and 3 as well?

Comment: Tried it with gfortran 4.2.3, 4.3.4, 4.4.3, 4.8.1 and 4.8.2. I can't reproduce your findings.

Comment: Just to be sure: Is there a flag `--disable-libgomp` when executing `gfortran -v`?

Comment: @Stefan no there is: --enable-libgomp look to the post, I have updated it with additional information.

Comment: @nykon: yes, I get 0, 1, 2, 3 for `tnr`.

Comment: @keyle so there must be sothing wrong in my linux-configuration/compiler or who knows what else. :(

Comment: Let's check if your compiler understands OpenMP. Could you please compile your code like this: `gfortran -fopenmp -fdump-tree-all source.f90` (substitute `source.f90` for the actual name of your source file). This will produce lots of files with names like `source.f90.NNN.something` where `NNN` is a 3-digit number. Find the file with the largest number that _does not_ contain `statistics` in its name (usually the one before the last) and then update your question with the content of that file.

Comment: I have updated the question with the content of the file.

Comment: And I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS` or calling `omp_set_num_threads()` sets the *nthreads-var* ICV (Internal Control Variable). To retrieve back its value, one should call `omp_get_max_threads()` and not `omp_get_num_threads()`.

Second, there is a data race in your code. By default OpenMP will treat both `tnr` and `t` **shared variables**. In that case the value of `tnr` displayed by the `write` statement will be the value obtained in the last thread to execute the assignment (note that GCC suppresses register optimisation when it comes to shared variables).

The correct code would be as follows:

```
program test

use omp_lib
implicit none

integer :: i, tnr,t 

call omp_set_num_threads( 4 )
t = omp_get_max_threads()

write(*,*)'t:',t

!$omp parallel do private(tnr)
do i = 1, 20
   tnr = omp_get_thread_num()
   write( *, * ) 'Thread', tnr, ':',  i
end do
!$omp end parallel do

end program test
```

Note that when a `do` construct is immediately and the only thing nested inside a `parallel` region, one could use the combined `parallel do` construct and save two lines of code.

---

You have stored Fortran 90 code in a `.f` file, which is therefore recognised as fixed source form. In this case the OpenMP directives must obey the following rules:

> The following sentinels are recognized in fixed form source files:
>
> `!$omp` | `c$omp` | `*$omp`
>
> Sentinels **must start in column 1** and appear as a single word with no intervening characters. Fortran fixed form line length, white space, continuation, and column rules apply to the directive line. Initial directive lines must have a space or zero in column 6, and continuation directive lines must have a character other than a space or a zero in column 6. (*emphasis mine*)

I guess your directives start in the same column as the rest of the program code and therefore are treated simply as comments and not as OpenMP directives, evident by the content of the `testmp.f.140t.optimized` file.

Comment: Good suggestion with the "omp_get_max_threads()". But still "tnr" shows "0" for each "i". Right now I tried the code on kubuntu machine, and still result is the same :/

Comment: Assume that your executable is called `test`. Does `libgomp.so` show somewhere in the output from `ldd test`?

Comment: look to the post I have updated it with some additional infroamtion.

Comment: @nykon, do you by any chance have an environment variable called `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` set to 1?

Comment: how to check this? typing just "export" in the shell I got a list of variables, but I see no variable OMP_THREAD_LIMIT.

Comment: What variables with names starting with OMP you have? What are their values? You might find the following command helpful: `export | grep ^OMP`

Comment: the command returns nothing, so what does it mean? is that correct?

Comment: It's ok - means no OpenMP environment variables are defined.

Comment: ok, thank You for help Hristo, I think something must be wrong with my gentoo configuration, BUT on the other hand everythink is there, I am able tocompile the code, no error is displayed; that is extreamly strange...

Answer (score 1):

At first, you have to compile this code with

```
gfortran -fopenmp FILE
```

The second thing is, that `omp_get_num_threads()` shows you the number of threads, at the point, where you are. As you called this function in a serial region, the answer is always `1`.

Comment: I compile the code with "-fopenmp". Inside the loop there is second function "omp_get_thread_num()" which should show me number of actual used thread, so this number shoud change from 0...3 (4 threads), BUT as You can see in the output the thread number is always "0".

Comment: The program would not link at all without `-fopenmp` being specified.

Comment: @Hristo which means? how can I specify -fopenmp?

Comment: @nykon: You specify `-fopenmp` as Stefan wrote in this answer and as I wrote in my comment to your question above. Hristo is saying that if you do not have `-fopenmp` in your compiler commands, it should not compile at all.

Comment: Yes that is correct. If I have no -fopenmp then the code does not compile at all.